# Getting the Overclocker achievement in Portal 2

Tags: achievements, portal-2

One of the achievements in Portal 2 is

> **Overclocker**
>
> Complete Test Chamber 10 in 70 seconds

There doesn't seem much room for error if you want to finish that room in under 70 seconds. Any tips on how to shave off a few more seconds in that level and get the achievement?

Comment: Quicksave before entering the room. You will get the achievement when you've placed the block on the final button. If you don't get the achievement, quickload.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a pretty quick execution of this room.

Comment: Compared to this video, my portal-playing has all the agility of an eagle. Piloting a blimp. :-(

Comment: This isn't even the fastest one I found; it's just the fastest comprehensible one.

Comment: Comprehensible is a relative term.

Answer (score 6):

I've now managed to get the achievement and I recorded a video to show a possible path to finish the room fast enough.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to shave off a few seconds is to remember that you have a portal gun - instead of walking over to the storage cube and the faith plate, shoot portals so that you can pop in one and out the other. Shooting portals is usually pretty quick, while movement takes a while.

Also, make sure you shoot a portal for the laser while you're on the upper level, making a redirection cube drop. You don't want to have to bounce up there more than once.

Answer (score 3):

1. Place one of your portals on the top-left as soon as you enter the room.
2. Place one of your portals at the same time you use the weighted storage cube to block the laser.
3. Push the storage cube off the ledge when you replace it with the discouragement redirection cube.  You need to jump back down to get to the aerial faith plate anyway.

Other than that, all I can tell you is: Be quick!